# Line of action of buoyant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, buoyancy

**Question:**
Show that the line of action of the buoyancy force on an arbitrarily shaped body submerged in a liquid passes through its center of mass

**My observation:** I know that buoyant force is equal to the weight of the submerged body. But how can I proceed further?

Comment: The buoyant force is equal to the weight of the liquid it displaces.

Comment: A net force that is not through the center of mass would produce a torque, and the object would continuously rotate in the liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My observation: I know that buoyant force is equal to the weight of
> the submerged body. But how can I proceed further?

Be careful.

The buoyant force is only equal to the weight of the submerged body if the submerged body is floating, that is, if the density of the submerged body is equal to or less than the density of the liquid. The maximum buoyant force occurs when the density of the body exactly equals the density of the liquid, in which case the body floats completely submerged.

If the density of the body is greater than the density of the liquid, the upward buoyant force will be less than the downward weight of the body and the body will sink. Once the body sinks there is no further displacement of the liquid which is responsible for the buoyant force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okay but it doesn't give an explanation about the line of action of buoyant force (passes through the center of mass)

Comment: We are not supposed to solve specific problems just address conceptual issues. I’ve addressed one (your observation). You haven’t told us the conceptual issues you are having with the question

Comment: @Alpha BobD was correctly addressing a misconception you have. However, users here shouldn't give solutions to homework problems. What about forces and the buoyant force are you confused about that is preventing you from solving this yourself? You should be asking about that instead.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I proceed further?

The buoyant force is actually a net force due to the interaction of each part of the surface of the object with each interface with the surrounding atmosphere (liquid or gas). On each little area of the surface there is a normal force contribution. The vector sum of all those small forces is the buoyant force.

Now consider an object floating in a liquid, e.g. water, in static equilibrium (in our inertial reference frame) with gravity and these small forces. We know the net force is zero. Now, think about the net torque, given that the object is not rotating. That should give you the information you need about the line of action of the (net) buoyant force.

If you push on one end of an extended object such that you lift part of it out of the liquid, the object will oscillate for a bit. That should tell you something about the net torque about the center of mass.

Finally, if an object is sinking in a liquid, quite often you will observe it to "flutter" or spiral as it falls. Different parts of the surface will have different local fluid velocities, producing different frictional forces making the line of action of the *net friction* be offline from the center of mass so that a torque is exerted as it falls.

Comment: so you mean to say that torque due to both weight and buoyant force are equal at any point (that means buoyant force should be directed opposite to the direction of weight and pass-through center of mass)

Comment: I think there is a typo, but other than that I think it's fine.

Comment: @Alpha I mean to say what I have written in the answer. You need to think about what has been said by me and Bob.